# What's going on with leaves on my avocado? help

Tags: diagnosis, tree-care, pest-control, avocado

I have an avocado plant in my outdoors, but for some time light spots appear on the leaves, and the tips dry out
[image: 1]

[image]

[image]

[image: 5]